# Change to EclipseLink ignore the @DateTimeFormat annotation and stop working with JodaTime

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jodatime

I change my application to EclipseLink to use the tenancy solution. That's ok until now.

The simple annotation:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Is ignored, and all my dates now returns this format:

```
Mon Mar 02 16:55:52 BRT 2015
```

The entity that use:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "org")
public class Organization {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    private Date startdate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I can't work with jodatime for this input. Anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Your question needs more specific information.

Should we assume you're using DateTimeFormat from joda?  (there is also one from Spring)
Should we assume that DateTimeFormat is on an Entity attribute?
Do you think it would help to provide a snippet of code where you're using this annotation?

Comment: Sure, that's right. I put the entitty into description. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean that the sql statements are issued with the wrong format. Or do you have the wrong format printed on the java side when you do for example toString()?

Comment: In jsp, when I show the result return in this format.

Answer (score 0):

The `@DateTimeFormat` informs how date should be represented in DB (when insert, or update statments are issued) so that the Java representation can match the "text" format of DB.

In JSP you see, how the Date value is rendered as text in Java. If you access it directly, it is simply the same as `startData.toString()`, so you see the default format for your locale;

You need to use `DateTimeFormat` for render the date as you want.
You can add `getJSPTime()` method to your POJO that uses that `DataTimeFormat` to produced the required String.